# MVC: ViewModel values will not display in datepicker using type="month"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Apologies if this has already been asked - I have been searching Google for an hour with no luck so figured I'd post here and see if I could get an answer.

I am building a web application using MVC 5 + Entity Framework. One of the modules that I am developing is a fuel card tracker which contains details about fuel cards attached to vehicles.

I have a basic view model called `FuelCardViewModel` which is the `FuelCard` model (from EF) with a few `SelectList` objects. One property I have is a `DateTime` property called `ExpiryDate` which will hold the expiry date of the card.

When I populate the view model and send it to the `Edit` view, all of the fields are automatically filled in using the values in the ViewModel **except** the `ExpiryDate` field. When this field is set to `type = "date"`, the value is pulled through and displayed correctly, so I know this isn't an issue with my ViewModel binding. Problem is, I want month/year **only**, so I have to use `type = "month"`. When it is set to `type = "month"` (to only display a month/year picker as per card expiry date formatting), the value does not display (although I can still see the value when I view the source and look at the `value` property. This further backs up the fact that the ViewModel binding is working correctly, but just the formatting is messed up when using a month picker instead of a normal date picker). Any help with this is much appreciated; if more info is required let me know and I can provide.

`ExpiryDate` property in `FuelCardViewModel`:

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM yyyy}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayName("Expiry Date")]
public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
```

If I want to use `type = "date"`, I have to change `{0:MMMM yyyy}` to `{0:yyyy-MM-dd}` as per other answers on here, so changing it to `{0:MMMM yyyy}` is just an attempt to fix the issue.

The field in my `Edit` view:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpiryDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpiryDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "month"} })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpiryDate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
 </div>
```

How the `Edit` view displays (with `type = "month"`):

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5VVt.png)

How the `Edit` view **should** display:

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70erH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this! Figured I would post the solution here to help those in need.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM yyyy}")]
```

should look like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM}")]
```

Such a simple error but my problem is now solved!